# The object used as boolean appears in the rendered image, even though it was disabled in the viewport

Tags: rendering, modifiers

[image]

When I applied the boolean modifier (and hide from view the cylinder at the bottom) it shows when I am editing. But when I render, the cylinder still shows up like in the picture, but when I duplicate (the one on the right), it works. How to fix this problem?

I'm using the blender 2.91 on windows

Comment: Did you exclude the cylinder from rendering.. like the other one?

Comment: To exclude from rendering use the camera icon https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7mzB.gif

Comment: TY!!! @susu that's what I wanted I thought I only needed to hide in viewport